# Importing from child directory without a relative path with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build

Given such a project structure:

```
project/
    src/
        CMakeLists.txt
        foo.h
        main.cpp
        util/
            CMakeLists.txt
            bar.h
```

Inside of `bar.h` is it possible to have an include statement as `#include "foo.h"` ? I've seen *some* possible ways to do this via "precompiled headers" configurations in Visual Studio, but not using CMake directly.

Comment: Assuming you have `project/src` directory among *include directories*, then `#include "foo.h"` will work. In CMake include directories are specified with [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/include_directories.html) command.

Comment: Also [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html) can be used.

Comment: This has nothing to do with precompiled headers.

Comment: What's wrong with `#include "../foo.h"`? And why does `util` reach into its parent? Sounds like poor design.

Comment: Poor design probably? This is a $200 billion open source project I'm trying to see how to improve the build system with CMake.

Comment: In that case, you probably don't want to have CMakeLists.txt in each directory. Just treat project/src/ as one source tree. And if you want to modularize the sources, move code to separate directories with one-directional dependencies.

Comment: @Ivorne Why not try to do it right the first time? Its more of a pain in the a$$ but, as you can imagine large projects move slow and tend not to go back quickly and improve certain things

Comment: @WilliamBright The point is that having a CMakeLists.txt for each directory in your source tree is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Good news is that compilation proces in CMake works with *target* dependencies, not with *file* dependencies. So you don't need to change your file hierarchy, you just need to modify target hierarchy, but not too much.

1. In file src/CMakeLists.txt, create extra INTERFACE target named for example *src_interface*

   ```
   add_library( src_interface INTERFACE )
   ```
2. Add your include directory to it:

   ```
   target_include_directories( src_interface INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
   ```
3. This needs to be done before you add util as subdirectory

   ```
   add_subdirectory( util )
   ```
4. In src/util/CMakeLists.txt, add linking to the interface:

   ```
   target_link_libraries( util_target PRIVATE src_interface )
   ```

More about INTERFACE libraries in CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries

Comment: Ok, I just tested it and it works well. Of course you need to properly integrate it with the rest of your CMakeLists.txt contents. One problem might be mixing of target-scoped commands with file-scoped commands. Another problem might be the target_link_libraries command where you need to put name of your actual util target. Just post your full build scripts if you want more help.